# Bluetooth in C++

Tags: c++, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am looking to communicate via RFCOMM to another Bluetooth device.  I want to use C++ (VS2008) for the application.  I already know of the 32feet library, but was unsure if it would work for C++.  Does anyone know of a good starting point for this kind of project?  Or possibly 32feet samples written in C++?  I want a simple, easy to use API for Bluetooth using C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do Bluetooth programming using BT sockets into the OS Bluetooth stack.  This page discusses socket usage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362928(v=vs.85).aspx

This page has links to download Bluetooth SDK from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363058(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

This question is rather old, I know.

Just wanted to update, that Qt Framework has now Qt Bluetooth for C++ that looks very promising -- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-module.html

Comment: No support on windows yet.`Currently, the API is supported on the following platforms: Android, iOS, Linux (BlueZ 4.x/5.x) and OS X` from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html)

Comment: Old questions tend to be the ones that pop up first on Google searches. :) Updating with new info is always good.

Comment: Qt's Bluetooth stack (as of May 2023) still has lots of bugs, even their examples don't work consistently.  Lost many dev hours trying to make the Qt BT stack work.

Comment: @TSG, I second that. It doesn't work properly and it shows different behavior on different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Building apps using the Microsoft stack works fairly well (XP and Vista work great, trying to run the same apps under Windows 7-64bit does not work so well...)

The real advantage to 32feet.net is that the Bluetooth support on Windows is heavily Balkanized - you never know on a given machine whether it is using the Microsoft, Broadcom, Toshiba, BlueSolei, or some other stack.  While these are all mostly compatible over-the-air, the APIs are completely different for each.  Building with 32feet.net lets your application run on a larger subset of machines...  That said, I have not tried building it into a C++ application - sorry.