# Bluetooth adapter is an USB (lsusb), what do I need to program it with c/c++(send and read data)?

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth

#### Bluetooth send and read data

So I'm learning how to interact with my peripherals, and I was reading about *Serial Programming* here:

- [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)
- [Serial Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/index.html)

I'm using Linux, I have an Arduino UNO and see that its port is on `/dev/ttyS0`  (almost all the time), I have the bluetooth module for the Arduino, now I'm trying to communicate my computer with the Arduino with that module.

But after researching I see that my Bluetooth adapter is actually an USB (?) (output from `lsusb`):

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My bluetooth adapter is this:

```
Bus: 002
Device: 004
Vendor ID: 0bda
Product ID: b728
```

How can I control my bluetooth adapter, I mean is it with Serial Programming? Because after more research I found that file descriptor for my device is on:

`/dev/bus/usb/002/004`

I'm very newbie with this kind of programming, I found a library called *[hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi)*, I followed the example and documentation (this lib can used *hidraw* or *libusb*) but it can't open my device, this is the example:

```
#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // hid_open(vendor_id, product_id, optional serial_number)
  // VendorID and ProductID according to lsusb output
  hid_device *device = hid_open(0xbda, 0xb728, NULL);

  if (!device) {
    printf("Can't open device!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Device successfully opened\n");

  wchar_t *product_str;
  hid_get_product_string(device, product_str, 255);  // 255 is MAX_LEN recommended string
  printf("%ls\n", product_str);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled both ways, no one worked.

- With *libhidapi-libusb*
  ```
  $ g++ -std=c++14 main.cc -lhidapi-libusb -o main
  $ ./main
  Can't open device!
  ```
- With *libhidapi-hidraw*
  ```
  $ g++ -std=c++14 main.cc -lhidapi-hidraw -o main
  $ ./main
  Can't open device!
  ```

Finally, these are my questions:

- Is something am I doing wrong?
- Programming the bluetooth usb is serial programming?
- Should I use purely libusb? If yes how can I send and read data?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. No. Use a library for [**bluetooth**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254910/bluetooth-in-c).

Comment: Already seen that ones, but I need it for Linux not Windows, founded bluez, I think I got it with this:

[An Introduction to Bluetooth Programming](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/index.html)

Comment: Try it. Or [Qt Bluetooth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-module.html). But serial programming refers to a **wired** cable standard (as does usb). As for the usb device, that is a bluetooth radio.

Comment: So serial programming is used with another kind of USB (Also have seen that it's used for MODEMs)? I will try Qt Bluetooth and BlueZ.

Comment: [Serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) ports predate USB. USB is a Universal Serial Bus (not a serial port).